# Post to Twitter failure: Error: You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth)…

Tags: javascript, npm, twitter

I have a JavaScript app running NPM Twit [https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit] to post to Twitter. My bot recently stopped working without explanation or warning. Twitter seemed to require me to upgrade from their old free tier to their new free tier, which required me to delete all content from my Twitter Dev account and then to recreate my project and app. I did so, and I made sure I chose read and write permissions.

My authorization is valid. When I run `twitClient.get('account/verify_credentials', {…})`, I receive all account details.

But something is preventing my code from tweeting. When I run `twitClient.post('statuses/update', {…}, function (error, success) {})`, I receive:

```
Post to Twitter failure: Error: You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product
    at exports.makeTwitError (/Users/…/node_modules/twit/lib/helpers.js:74:13)
    at onRequestComplete (/Users/…/node_modules/twit/lib/twitter.js:344:25)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/…/node_modules/twit/lib/twitter.js:364:7)
    at Request.emit (node:events:523:35)
    at Gunzip.<anonymous> (/Users/…/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:625:28)
    at Gunzip.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1367:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 453,
  allErrors: [
    {
      message: 'You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product',
      code: 453
    }
  ],
  twitterReply: { errors: [ [Object] ] },
  statusCode: 403
}
```

I’ve tried swapping out Twit for something newer like Twitter API V2 [https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-api-v2], but that syntax for tweeting is completely different.

I tried searching for answers, but I only found Python code.

Comment: You need to tweet with the V2 API as V1.1 no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

POST /2/tweets is currently under the free plan, so you should be able to post tweets without upgrading in v2.
check this doc, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/migrate as you already found some code so I'm not including it.

From the documentation, to make it more clear to you,

" The v2 manage Tweets endpoints will replace the standard v1.1 POST statuses/update and POST statuses/destroy/:id endpoints. If you have code, apps, or tools that use the v1.1 version of the manage Tweets endpoints and are considering migrating to the newer Twitter API v2 endpoint, then this set of guides is for you. "